# Increment Regex match using Regex.Replace

Tags: regex, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm creating a program in VB.NET to output multiple images. Some images will have the same file name. If there is multiple files with the same name I want to add "_1_" to the end of the file name. If the "_1_" file already exists I want to increment the 1 to be "_2_". If this file already exists I want to continue incrementing the number ultil it doesn't exist. So for example "filename", filename_1_", "filename_2_", etc. Here is the code that I have tried

```
Dim usedFiles As New List(Of String)
While usedFiles.Contains(returnValue)
    If Regex.IsMatch(returnValue, "[_]([0-9]{1,})[_]$") Then
        returnValue = Regex.Replace(returnValue, "[_]([0-9]{1,})[_]$", "_" + (CType("$1", Integer) + 1).ToString() + "_")
    Else
        returnValue += "_1_"
    End If
End While
usedFiles.Add(returnValue)
```

The line that isn't working is:

```
returnValue = Regex.Replace(returnValue, "[_]([0-9]{1,})[_]$", "_" + (CType("$1", Integer) + 1).ToString() + "_")
```

which outputs "filename_2_" every time. I have also tried:

```
returnValue = Regex.Replace(returnValue, "[_]([0-9]{1,})[_]$", "_($1+1)_")
```

however this returns "filename_($1+1)_". I know I could just remove the "_" then add 1 to the number then put the "_" back on both sides, but I also know this can be done in other languages (like php) using the Regex.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't taken the time to figure out what's wrong with your RegEx expression because it just seems silly to me.  You're over thinking it.  All you need to do is something simple like this:

```
Dim fileName As String = returnValue
Dim i As Integer = 0
While usedFiles.Contains(returnValue)
    i = i + 1
    returnValue = fileName + "_" + i.ToString() + "_"
End While
```

Comment: Ok. Now think about if the fileName or returnValue is already "filename_1_". Your way would then output "filename_1__1_" instead of "filename_2_".

Comment: Ok.  I assumed your code was generating the file name so it would never have the number on the end like that in the first place, but if that's an issue, you could always still use my logic and just strip the "_#_" off the beginning of `fileName` first.

Comment: Ok. I completely mis-read your code. Sorry about that. Your code would work. After coding for hours on end somehow I actually read your code as: returnValue = returnValue + "_" + i.ToString() + "_". After taking a break from coding I realized I can't read. I was able to get it working with the Regex, but just not the one line Regex like what I was looking for. O well. Thanks!